# Some Wordpress product pages messed up

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Im facing with problem on some of products pages under woocommerce. Some of them look like this https://stream-tek.com/product/adjustable-air-amplifier/ but others are just fine, for example, same product with almost exact variations looks like this: https://stream-tek.com/product/hi-temp-adjustable-air-amplifier/ and I cant find the problem.

What could be causing this issue?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I visited both links and they both look good.

Comment: The problem that you got in the first page is **a javascript error** that makes your Image slider not working… You should check with your browser console and you will see that.